# "Missing '{' inserted" and "Missing } inserted" with aligned environment

Tags: math-mode, macros, errors, amsmath

I'm trying to write something out some math in LaTeX with two aligned columns using the `aligned` environment, which seems to have the best results so far. Using the following code, I have no issue, and it comes out pretty much exactly as I want it to:

```
\[
    \begin{aligned}[c]
        f(x) &= e^{-4x}\\
        f'(x) &= -4e^{-4x}
    \end{aligned}
    \qquad
    \begin{aligned}[c]
        f(0) &= e^0 = 1\\
        f'(0) &= -4e^0 = -4
    \end{aligned}
\]
```

But I'll be doing this a lot in the document I'm working on, so I want to make this a command. The code I use for the command is

```
\newcommand{\mtable}[2]{
    \[
        \begin{aligned}[c]
            {#1}
        \end{aligned}
        \qquad
        \begin{aligned}[c]
            {#2}
        \end{aligned}
    \] 
    }
```

but now when I try to use this command in the same way, like so

```
\mtable{
    f(x) &= e^{-4x}\\
    f'(x) &= -4e^{-4x}
}{
    f(0) &= e^0 = 0\\
    f'(0) &= -4e^0 = -4
}
```

I get two errors that say `Missing { Inserted.` and two errors that say `Missing } inserted.` all pointing to the last line in the previous block of code. As far as I can tell, there's no unmatched parentheses, and I've tried removing the parentheses around `{#1}` and `{#2}` from the command definition but nothing has quite worked, so I'm not sure what's wrong with this code.

Forgive me if this is a duplicate question, but for most other similar questions I've found, the answer has been that there was an incorrect `\left` or `\right`, and I don't think that applies in my case.

Edit: Playing around with it some more, I've found that the issue seems to be the newline command (`\\`). When I remove it, I don't get the error, but obviously I also don't get new lines where I need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop your use of braces around the arguments `#1` and `#2` in your `\mtable` definition:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mtable}[2]{%
  \[
    \begin{aligned}[c]
      #1
    \end{aligned}
    \qquad
    \begin{aligned}[c]
      #2
    \end{aligned}
  \] 
}

\begin{document}

\mtable{
  f(x)  &=   e^{-4x} \\
  f'(x) &= -4e^{-4x}
}{
  f(0)  &=   e^0 =  0 \\
  f'(0) &= -4e^0 = -4
}

\end{document}
```

The braces are split across `&` and `\\` when placed inside the `aligned` environment, and this cannot be done.

Comment: That works! I thought I tried that but apparently not! Thank you!